# How to maintain Lottie animation progress across different recompositions

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lottie

I'm trying to use Lottie compose for playing animation in compose. But the animation starts from the very beginning for all recompositions. I wish to maintain the current playback and not restart the animation for each recomposition. Here is my current code

```
@Composable
fun Loader() {
    val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.main))
 LottieAnimation(composition)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to save animation progress outside of the composable functions, that will be recomposed

```
  @Composable
fun ParentComposable() {
    val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.main))
    val animationProgress by animateLottieCompositionAsState(composition = composition)

    ChildComposable(animationProgress = animationProgress, composition = composition)
}

@Composable
fun ChildComposable(animationProgress: Float, composition: LottieComposition?) {
    ...
    Loader(progress = animationProgress, composition = composition)
    ...
}

@Composable
fun Loader(animationProgress: Float, composition: LottieComposition?) {
    ...
    LottieAnimation(composition, animationProgress)
    ...
}
```