# How to play Lottie animation from start every time in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation, lottie, compose-recomposition

I have a screen showing a Lottie animation; however, the content of the screen changes and so the animation. I'm showing the animation only once and I need that when the content of the screen gets updated (recomposition), the updated animation starts playing. Currently the first animation plays all the way up to the end and when the content changes the second animation shows only a static image which I assume is its last frame.

Here is the code snippet I'm using:

```
val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.animation))
val progress by animateLottieCompositionAsState(composition = composition)
LottieAnimation(
    composition = composition,
    progress = { progress },
    modifier = modifier
)
```

I've tried making the progress `0F` but then animations don't load or don't play since I can see no content but maybe that's only the first frame, that would be the below code snippet:

```
val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.animation))
LottieAnimation(
    composition = composition,
    progress = { 0F },
    modifier = modifier
)
```

My goal is to show both animations from the start regardless of wether the first one finished or not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You are remembering Lottie animation state, so after recomposition it will not play again since its state came to the end stage and is passed to next composition.

Have you tried setting up the `isPlaying` parameter?

```
val composition by rememberLottieComposition(...)
val animationState by animateLottieCompositionAsState(
    composition = composition, 
    isPlaying = true
)

LottieAnimation(
    composition = composition,
     progress = { animationState },
     modifier = modifier
)
```

UPD: You can also simply remove `animationState` remembering.

```
val composition by rememberLottieComposition(...)

LottieAnimation(
    composition = composition,
)
```

UPD2: Since Compose can optimize recompositions and recompose only what has actually changed, your Lottie animation is probably not recomposed at all. Maybe you should loop it like this

```
val animationState by animateLottieCompositionAsState(
    composition = composition, 
    iterations = LottieConstants.IterateForever
)
```

Comment: Actually I was playing around with those options and they didn't work either. I tried something similar to your 1st approach but didn't work, in your case I get a compilation error in "progress = animationState.progress", apparently there is no progress inside that state. The 2nd approach gives me the same result I was getting with my snippet.

Comment: @AlejandroCasanova I am sorry, I added another theory and third solution. Can you try it as well? If it won't work, I would like to see the whole composable code to understand your composable structure

Comment: Sure thanks. Actually that "works", I tried that from the beginning to make sure the 2nd animation was working properly. Saddly it doesn't work for me because I cannot loop, the animation is supposed to play only once :(

Comment: @AlejandroCasanova check out this question, the OP said his Lottie works just as you want it to work, which is not the suit for him https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69306938/how-to-maintain-lottie-animation-progress-across-different-recompositions

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same problem, and wrapping up the composable with the `key` element did the trick.

So in your case, it'd look like

```
val key = remember { mutableStateOf(dynamicAnimationRes) }
if (key.value != dynamicAnimationRes) {
    key.value = dynamicAnimationRes
}

key(key.value) {
    val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(dynamicAnimationRes))
    LottieAnimation(
        composition = composition,
        modifier = modifier
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make lottie animation repeat forever like this :

```
val composition by rememberLottieComposition(
    spec = LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.animation)
)

LottieAnimation(
    modifier = Modifier,
    composition = composition,
    iterations = LottieConstants.IterateForever
)
```

or play just once after recomposition like this :

```
val composition by rememberLottieComposition(
    spec = LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.animation)
)

LottieAnimation(
    modifier = Modifier,
    composition = composition,
    restartOnPlay = true
)
```